# Is it possible to model percentage variable using a logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have a variable (`V`) corresponding to a percentage of cell (human B cells) that I want to explain by 3 variable (`X`,`Y`,`Z`) corresponding to an absence/presence of 3 different treatments.
May I use a logistic regression as

```
glm(V~X*Y*Z, family=binomial(link="logit"),data)
```

?

```
     V X Y Z 
 0.083 0 0 0 
 0.862 1 0 1 
 0.336 1 0 0 
 0.134 1 0 1 
 0.493 1 0 1 
 0.121 1 0 0 
 0.307 0 0 0 
 0.404 1 0 0 
 0.088 1 1 1
```

My variable `V` to explain is not stochastic but is between 0 and 1

Comment: not easily. Beta regression would be better (e.g. see `betareg` R package).  This is on the verge of a CrossValidated (http://stats.stackexchange.com) question.

Comment: Do you have the actual counts corresponding to the percentages?

Comment: A couple notes, Your random variable V is stochastic otherwise it would be deterministic.  You might be trying to say it is not a probability.

Why do you want to use a logistic regression?  Don't you want to output percentages?  You might want to use linear regression for your initial analysis, this may not be an issue if you have sufficiently small variance or most of your values are sufficiently far away from 0 or 1.  I would look into GLMs when you have a better feel for the process generating your data.

Comment: If you have actual count data, as @Dason pointed out, you could do a logistic regression. See first example in `?glm`.